# Hadoop on EC2 vs. ElasticMapReduce/S3

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have used ElasticMapReduce for some time. It is quite convenient but I can't run HBase since Hadoop cluster is only temporarily available (I have asked somewhat related question at [HBase and Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935863/hbase-and-hadoop)).

So I want to try out installing Hadoop on a set of EC2 machines. I know Hadoop has some EC2 related directory - src/contrib/ec2. It looks like a Hadoop cluster can be launched simply by typing a command and I can log into a master node to run jobs and so on. Before trying this, I would like to know any gotchas from ppl who have been using this. Thanks!

Comment: Good question, would love to see some answers too. I know that Elastic MapReduce uses S3 as it's storage platform, so it is usually less efficient than Hadoop on EC2 since it can't use the data locality optimization like it would with HDFS (s3 runs on a different system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed there are two options of using hadoop on amazon - provisioning of you own cluster or usint EMR. Orthogonal to this decision you can use HDFS or S3 as your file system.
It is not short story but I will try to highligt some pros/cons of all these choices. 
You can use EMR if you need to run single / few jobs a day and do not need hadoop cluster all the time. In this case you put your data into s3 and can fully script the process. Main disadvatage - it is not easy to customize, use third party libraries etc. In this case you also save time of installing the cluster.
If you want to tweak hadoop - you should install your own cluster. 
When your data is already in s3 or you need to store it after processings - s3 is a good choice. In the same time - you will get probabbly less performance then using HDFS. Have to be stated that amazon instances has very little local storage - so it get really expensive and you should keep cluster running (and pay for it) just to preserve this storage. 
I would tell that if you indeed need HDFS with all its throuput you indeed need own cluster on own hardware. When you working on Amazon - it is most practical to use S3 as your file system.